# How to resolve 'Javascript Error: IPython is not defined' while trying to plot interactively in a jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, matplotlib, ipython

I would like to interactively plot in jupyter notebook. While using matplotlib.pyplot and trying to plot interactively through the code below, I get the error `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This error has appeared after I updated the anaconda. I have searched in the internet for a solution, but could not solve the issue in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

The `notebook` backend does not work in jupyter-lab (i.e. the problem is your line `%matplotlib notebook` which specifies the "notebook" backend for matplotlib)... You have to switch to [ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) for interactive plots for jupyter-lab or for jupyter notebook v7!

First install it, e.g.

```
pip install ipympl
```

then you can activate it with

```py
%matplotlib widget
```

Comment: It works in Jupyter Notebook 7+, too. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) about installation and trying the Basic Example below that. Specifically because you are using Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager, run in the notebook where you want to use it `%conda install -c conda-forge ipympl`. Let it run and complete. (Anaconda takes a bit of time.) As it is a rather complex install, I suggest restarting Jupyter and your browser in addition to just the kernel for all the settings to propagate fully. (I tested it just now in Jupyter Notebook Version: 7.1.0a2 on a ...

Comment: <continued> remote computer and restarting the kernel and refreshing the browser page in Chrome was sufficient to get the Basic Example to work after installing. You can try it by [clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/jtpio/83b0b625cb3b6e05d7f3d8714f98182e/master?urlpath=/tree) without touching your own system by using a temporary remote machine provided my the MyBinder.org system.) And you can use `%matplotlib ipympl` explicitly to better remind yourself of the package involved; the `widget` option remains for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First install it:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
```

you can activate it with

```
%matplotlib widget
```